# Finding algebraic expression for the equivalence

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Algebraically finding common values for division by modulus : $m \mid a^2 $

Now, given a range of integer values, say $a = \{1,...,m-1\}$ for modulus $m$, the values of squares ($a^2$) will range from $\{1,...,(m-1)^2\}$. If need find the remainder for $m \mid a^2$; then would need consider only the remainders from $1,..., \dfrac {m-1}{2}$, as the rest of the values will be repeated in the reverse order. For the purpose of question, have excluded the value of $a=0$ for odd value of modulus. As the value not being repeated in reverse, for odd modulus.

Say, m = 5 and need find remainder for $5 \mid a^2 \in \{1, 2^2, 3^2,4^2\}$. the values of remainders are: $ 1, 4, 4, 1$. So, $r = 1$ yields the same remainder as $m-r(=1) =4$.

I request finding an algebraic expression for stating the equal values of remainders after $\dfrac {m-1}{2}$. My attempt is as follows:

The remainders for 
$m \mid r^2 => m \mod (m-a)^2 (= m^2 +a^2 -2ma)  => m -2a + (m \mid a^2)$  --(i)

But, the sum of the first two factors, i.e. $m - 2a$, cannot be stated by me to equal the 3rd factor ($ m \mid a^2 $) in the expression. 
It is obvious that $a$ is same as $m-r$ in reverse order, i.e. the value of $a = 1$ for $r=4$, and a = 2 for $r =3$, and so on.

If substitute expression of $m - r$ for $a$, still get no progress.

I can think of like below (not successful) to get the equality:

a) Having the values of $m -2r$ being equal to $m \mid r^2$, i.e. $(m -2r) = \dfrac{r^2}{m}$. But, it is useless.

b) Take value of $\dfrac{m-1}{2}$, as found by putting values, and try to show algebraically that the values from $1..\dfrac{m-1}{2}$ yield the same remainder as for values from $(\dfrac{m-1}{2}+1)$ to $m-1$.

Comment: I request help, as I feel there is a small missing link and would be a great help for a beginner like me in constructing such algebraic expressions in future.

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue

Comment: @lhf Thanks for answering in-spite of so unclear language and typos/errors. I will edit the OP soon.